# Checking if a string needs to call String.replaceAll() vs calling it

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

Sorry if the title is misleading/bad, wasnt sure how to word this question.

I have multiple lists of strings, and most of them will contain parameters that I need to replace a string with. Some of these strings (in the list) will contain multiple parameters to replace.

Ex

```
Comp Status `%compname`
Comp SLA `%rackname` `%sgname` `%compname`
```

I will need to replace anything within the graves `%----` with a string, which depends on the position in a for loop.

My question is, should I check the string to see if it has one of these parameters i need to switch, or should i just call all the replaceAll() statements on every string.

1.

```
for(String s: rackStr){
    newString = new String[1];                
    s = s.replaceAll("`%rackname`", rName);
    s = s.replaceAll("`%compname`", compName);
    s = s.replaceAll("`%sysname`", sysName);
    newString[0] = s;
    System.out.println(newString[0]);
    vars.add(newString);
}
```

2.

```
for(String s: rackStr){
    newString = new String[1];       
    if(s.contains("`%rackname")){         
        s = s.replaceAll("`%rackname`", rName);
    }
    if(s.contains("`%compname")){         
    s = s.replaceAll("`%compname`", compName);
    }

    if(s.contains("`%sysname")){         
        s = s.replaceAll("`%sysname`", sysName);
    }

    newString[0] = s;
    System.out.println(newString[0]);
    vars.add(newString);
}
```

Note i have to make newString an array, and add it to an List vars so i can write the entire vars variable to a CSV file via OpenCSV writeAll();

So should I use 1 or 2? Or something different?

Comment: I would simply do vars.add(new String[] {s}); instead of creating a new variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't invoke `replaceAll` if you're not using regular expressions to define your values to be replaced (in your case, they are clearly constant values so no need to abstract pattern definitions).

Use `replace` instead (it **will** replace all occurrences found).

It will internally invoke `Matcher#replaceAll`, but with constant values representing your fields to replace.

Invoking `contains` before invoking `replace` would not make a lot of sense, as you'd parse the `String` twice.

If the `String` doesn't contain the term to replace, no exception will be thrown: it just won't replace it.

You can also chain invocations for some eye candy:

```
s = s
    .replace("`%rackname`", rName)
    .replace("`%compname`", compName)
    .replace("`%sysname`", sysName);
```

Comment: Surprising that the [documentation for `replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) doesn't explicitly say it will return the same string object if no changes were made. That's what I would expect it to do, [what it does on Oracle's JDK](http://ideone.com/Eh2Iqi), but apparently doesn't guarantee it. Odd. (I was going to suggest saying that it did that, you see, but...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree the docs could be a little more explicit. However it seems pretty obvious that it would, since no exception is thrown other than `NPE` when target or replacement is `null`.

Comment: I didn't mean it would throw an exception, we know it doesn't do that. Just possibly do more work than required (duplicating the string). Now, **I** know it won't, and **you** know it won't, but the docs really should *say so*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Got it. By the way, also worth noting as a curiosity: `replace` actually invokes `replaceAll` internally. Not that the docs for `replaceAll` are any more explicit about that.

Comment: Thanks for the info, didn't realize replace would replace all the instances found.

Comment: @EricG you're welcome. I know, semantically it feels like an ambiguous naming choice...

Comment: @Mena: It calls *`Matcher#replaceAll`*, not `String#replaceAll`. But yeah, it uses the regex engine. Seems an odd choice.

Answer (score 1):

Prefer first way, because you need not to check in the first place weather it contains or not. And I would like to write the 3 lines in one line

```
s = s.replaceAll("`%rackname`", rName).replaceAll("`%compname`", compName).replaceAll("`%sysname`", sysName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple truth is that it depends.

The check itself has overhead, but the replace is not free.

If you had LOTS of different parameters, then at some point it would be cheaper to parse out exactly which parameters rather than blindly applying them all, since likely the majority wouldn't apply.

If your strings were particularly long, it would make sense also so as to not unnecessarily repeatedly parse the strings.

The most efficient technique is to do it in a stream, parsing the string just once, and applying the replacements as they show up.

But for 3 parameters over some short strings, simply brute force replacement while not not the most efficient in runtime, is far more efficient in development and maintenance. And the difference in runtime efficiencies is likely not enough to matter in the application.

Comment: Yea I will be testing the run time of doing these all, but i really doubt it will affect my program much, as it only does this right before it writes the strings to a file. Would be a good idea to throw this function into its own thread if it takes a few seconds to avoid the UI from locking?